# I have both 159 contacts and no contacts, according to different screens of the 'People' app on my new phone

Tags: contacts, titanium-backup, data-transfer

This is insanely weird.  If anyone can shed light on it, please help.

I'm migrating from CM11 on a Samsung to CM11 on a Sony Xperia (both unlocked+rooted, and without GApps installed). I've done this with Titanium Backup 6 maybe a hundred times, and also used my phones without Gapps since the start, both have been 100% straightforward so far.

This time I backed up contacts on the Samsung with Titanium and restored to the Sony, but the "People" app promptly said I have no contacts. I couldn't get it to show any of the contacts restored by Titanium. Never had that before. It let me create a contact but Titanium's restore failed.

I tried instead using "backup contacts" and restoring, with a .vcf file. That worked and showed 159 contacts imported, but when I use the 3-dots menu to "delete contacts" it insists there are no contacts. Press back key and it lists 159 contacts. Press delete option and it tells me I have no contacts.....

How can the same (standard) 'People' app tell me on one screen I have 159 contacts then when I try to delete them, tell me I don't have any contacts? I haven't done anything beyond importing contacts!